# Increasing default dpi value of jpg and png image in Phantomjs source files for page.render function

Tags: phantomjs, dpi

I am using **page.render()** function in **Phantomjs** to create images from web page containing svg elements. The rendered image has dpi of 72 in my ubuntu machine.

After a long searching in web I found that the default dpi value for ubuntu is 72. The resulted jpg image does not have good quality so I want to increase its dpi value (resolution).

**Can I change the value in phantomjs source files? If yes, then what are the files I need to change to set a higher dpi value?**

Comment: You mean change the dpi, recompile PhantomJS and run?

Comment: yes. I want to change the value in source files and then recompile it. is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improving jpeg image quality using scaling in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456142/improving-jpeg-image-quality-using-scaling-in-java)